# How to get between first and last of a specific node in an XML file?

Tags: xml, regex, xpath

Consider I have a file which contains the following data:

```
  ...
    <wsdl:message>
      ...
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message>
      ...
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message>
      ...
    </wsdl:message>
  ...
```

What would be an appropriate regex to get all data between the first `<wsdl:message>` and the last `</wsdl:message>`?

Or alternatively, (as has been suggested), an appropriate XPath solution.

The main idea is that I would like to find and replace that portion of data.

Comment: Using XPATH would be better that using regular expressions in my opinion.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I have edited the question to consider your suggestion... If you can provide a solution, that would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just use**:

```
//x:message/node()
```

where the prefix `x:` is bound (in the programming language that is *hosting* XPath) to the wsdl namespace -- this is often called "registering a namespace").

**Alternatively, if you aren't able to register this namespace, use**:

```
//*[local-name()='message' 
  and 
    namespace-uri() = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'
    ]/node()
```

Answer (score 0):

The XPath

```
/*/wsdl:message[fn:position() > 1 and fn:position() < fn:last()]
```

should do it.

**EDIT**

For XPath 1.0 (and code for PHP)

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:wsdl="/">
    <wsdl:message> 
      One
    </wsdl:message> 
    <wsdl:message> 
      Two 
    </wsdl:message> 
    <wsdl:message> 
      Three 
    </wsdl:message> 
    <wsdl:message> 
      Four 
    </wsdl:message> 
    <wsdl:message> 
      Five 
    </wsdl:message> 
    <wsdl:message> 
      Six 
    </wsdl:message>
</root>
XML;

print $string;
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

print_r($xml->xpath('/*/wsdl:message[position() > 1'.
                    ' and position() < last()]'));

?>
```

Comment: position() and last() are 'native' xpath functions. You don't need to prefix them with fn:

Comment: @DominicCronin - XPath 2.0 uses `fn:position`. Updated Answer to include code for PHP (Xpath 1.0) as an exaple.

Comment: @EdHeal: The `fn:` namespace prefix is used in the XPath 2.0 spec to show which functions are callable by the user. It's not necessary to use `fn:` in actual XPath code. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-concat where the example shows `concat()` being called without the namespace prefix.